# How Can I show SnackBar under FragmentDialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-snackbar

I have an activity with `FragmentDialog`. In `onResume` of this dialog I set height and weight of it to 80% and 90% by code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
layoutParams.copyFrom(getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes());
layoutParams.width = (int)(screenWidth * 0.9);
layoutParams.height = (int)(screenHeight * 0.8);

getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

It works perfectly, background has shadow, foreground `FragmentDialog` has proper dimensions. Question is - how can I show `SnackBar` at the bottom of the screen not affected by `FragmentDialog` (one that has shadow, Activity view) without shadow? Is there any way to disable shadow for specific view at activity that is in background of `FragmentDialog`?

Comment: Have you find a way?

Comment: @Shirane85 nope...

Answer (score 6):

Material design documentation says "[Snackbars appear above most elements on screen, and they are equal in elevation to the floating action button. However, they are lower in elevation than dialogs, bottom sheets, and navigation drawers](https://material.google.com/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage)". From there, I think you should consider displaying the `Snackbar` inside the `DialogFragment` or just display a small dialog on top of it.

If you want to display `Snackbar` inside dialog fragment, you could do something like this:

```
public void showSnackBar(final View parent, final String text) {
    Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(parent, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    sb.show();
}
```

- NOTE: `parent` is the entire dialog's view. You could improve it by making the root view of the fragment a `CoordinatorLayout` and showing the `Snackbar` on that view.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but there is a solution I think may be useful for others.
 To disable the dialog fragment shadow (in fact it is called DIM), add below code to your dialog fragment `onResume` method.
For Kotlin:

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        dialog?.window!!.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)  
    }
```

For Java:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(getActivity()!=null)
        getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    }
```

by the this is not exactly what question is asking but this will omit all the shadow behind dialog fragment.
To show snackbar in you parent fragment rather than your dialog fragment, you can pass parent fragment reference to dialog fragment constructor and instantiate snackbar with parent's view. this will show the snackbar at the bottom of parent fragment.
`showSnackbar` method would be like this:

For Kotlin:

```
private fun showSnackbar(messege: String) = 
        Snackbar.make(parent.view!!, messege, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

For Java:

```
private void showSnackBar(String messege) {
    if (parent.getView() != null)
        Snackbar.make(parent.getView(), messege, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

dialog fragment complete code would be like:
For kotlin:

```
class MyDialogFramgent(parent: Fragment) : DialogFragment() {
    // class code ...

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        dialog?.window!!.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
    }

    private fun showSnackbar(messege: String) =
            Snackbar.make(parent.view!!, messege, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

For Java:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private Fragment parent;

    public MyDialogFragment(Fragment parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getActivity() != null)
            getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    }

    private void showSnackBar(String messege) {
        if (parent.getView() != null)
            Snackbar.make(parent.getView(), messege, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```