# How to call findViewById(android.R.id.content) from dialogFragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to call snack bar in dialog fragment. But it shows on top of system buttons. To avoid this I need to call `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` in snack bar call. But not sure how to make it correct way.

In parent fragment I am calling this way

```
        Snackbar.make(requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "fdfdfdf", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and it works perfectly but the problem is that dialogfragment is on top of the snack bar so its not visible. So I need to call it from dialog fragment. But when I call it from dialog snack bar not visible.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38851714/9851608) probably answers your question

Answer (score 0):

> Make your dialog layout fullscreen with transparent background and keep your dialog content inside it and then while showing the snackBar give rootview of the dialog layout.

[Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150711/11831226]

Comment: is there a code sample? Btw my dialog is match parent with the view inside it which is not transparent will it be a problem?